# Bug in React Admin pagination

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I was trying to display a big list on the console which was working fine but upon adding pagination to the list it does not work as expected. 
At first, it just displays all the list items(100) and then upon clicking on next it does limit the list items(10) to the limit set for pagination. It should paginate the list upon first rendering also which it is not doing. 
This is a serious bug in react admin and one should look into this.

Comment: If it's a bug in a third party library, report it to the maintainers. We can't help much with code you don't own. Whether it belongs in SO or their issue tracker, though, a [mre] would be helpful.

Comment: If you can made a minimal reproducible example, this is a bug from RA. Otherwise it's on your side.